# Execution time for my Naive bayes classifier using python

Tags: python

I want to compare two classifiers according the execution time for each . How can i measure the execution time of a classifier such as naive bayes ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general method to compare the execution time of two implementations of a function, using the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module:

Suppose that you have two modules, `first.py` and `second.py`, that both implement a class called `FirstClassifier` and `SecondClassifier` respectively, both implementing a method called `classify`. Also suppose that they have a method called `train`, which when called reads some training data and trains its model, and you want to measure the speed of the `classify` method.

So first.py would be:

```
# Fill in imports here.
import random

class FirstClassifier(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # Fill in initialization code here.
        pass

    def train(self):
        # Fill in code to train model here.
        pass

    def classify(self, text):
        # Fill in classification code here.
        # Dummy "classification":
        return random.choice(['sports', 'politics', 'video games'])
```

And second.py would be:

```
# Fill in imports here.

class SecondClassifier(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # Fill in initialization code here.
        pass

    def train(self):
        # Fill in code to train model here.
        pass

    def classify(self, text):
        # Fill in classification code here.
        # Dummy "classification":
        return 'sports'
```

You can time the execution of the `classify` method using `timeit` like so:

```
python -m timeit -s 'from first import FirstClassifier;classifier = FirstClassifier();classifier.train();' 'classifier.classify("The game ended in a draw.")'
```

Sample output, indicating that classification of "The game ended in a draw." takes 0.417 μseconds on average.

```
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.417 usec per loop
```

And for the second implementation:

```
python -m timeit -s 'from second import SecondClassifier;classifier = SecondClassifier();classifier.train();' 'classifier.classify("The game ended in a draw.")'
```

Sample output, indicating that classification of "The game ended in a draw." takes 0.0836 μseconds on average.

```
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0836 usec per loop
```

The general form of these `timeit` commands is `python -m timeit -s 'SETUP_CODE' 'CODE_TO_TIME'`. So, code that needs to be executed to prepare the function to be measured goes to the `-s` option, and the main expression to be timed goes to the command's first non-flag argument.